# Update a table with the newest data without deleting and duplicating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that executes every 2 hours on a job agent that populates a table . The stored procedure DELETES everything out of the table and then reinserts everything back in.  This is detrimental to any reports using this table because while the job agent is executing there is no data for a short period of time.

What I need to do is just have the sp insert the newest rows into the table with out any deletion and without duplicating everything.

The table I'm inserting in to is similar to below.

```
 unique        CALL_TIME         ACTUAL_STOP       CAR
   1           10:40                 A             B2
   1           10:42                 C             C3
   2           15:40                 NULL          B2
   3           15:45                 A             E5
   3           15:45                 A             E6
   3           15:45                 A             E1
```

This I what've tried

```
 CREATE TABLE #tempSP

            (
        [Unique] [varchar](20),
        [CALL_TIME] [datetime] ,
        [ACTUAL_STOP] [varchar](10),
                    
                    [CAR] [varchar] (5)


            )

 INSERT INTO #tempSP

  SELECT 
  [Unique],
  [CALL_TIME],
  [ACTUAL_STOP],

  [CAR]

  FROM Table


 select * from #tempSP as s

 where   Not exists  

 ( 

 select * from [dbo].[test_table] as tt
 where s.unique = tt.unique
```

Output of this would be something similar to below, as you can see a row has been added which is great, that's what I want. But 'Unique 2' still has an ACTUAL_STOP of NULL.  This field is often the last thing to be populated in our system, so for it to be NULL for a while is not unusual, however once it does get populated it never updates using this method.

```
   unique      CALL_TIME         ACTUAL_STOP       CAR
   1           10:40                 A             B2
   1           10:42                 C             C3
   2           15:40                 NULL          B2
   3           15:45                 A             E5
   3           15:45                 A             E6
   3           15:45                 A             E1
   4           09:10                 B             B2
```

I've also tried MERGE, This method brings back the same as above, still has the problem of not updating the ACTUAL_STOP field.

```
  CREATE TABLE #tempSP

            (
        [Unique] [varchar](20),
        [CALL_TIME] [datetime] ,
        [ACTUAL_STOP] [varchar](10),

                    [CAR] [varchar] (5) 

            )

 INSERT INTO #tempSP

  SELECT 
  [Unique],
  [CALL_TIME],
  [ACTUAL_STOP],

  [CAR] 

  FROM Table


 select * from #tempSP as s

MERGE [dbo].[test_table] as d

USING #tempSP as s

ON (d.unique = s.unique)

WHEN MATCHED AND d.unique = s.unique

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([unique], [CALL_TIME], [ACTUAL_STOP], [CAR])
                       VALUES(s.[unique],s.[CALL_TIME], s.[ACTUAL_STOP], s.[CAR])
```

Also added UPDATE SET

```
   CREATE TABLE #tempSP

            (
        [Unique] [varchar](20),
        [CALL_TIME] [datetime] ,
        [ACTUAL_STOP] [varchar](10) ,

                    [CAR] [varchar] (5)

            )

 INSERT INTO #tempSP

  SELECT 
  [Unique],
  [CALL_TIME],
  [ACTUAL_STOP],

  [CAR]

  FROM Table


 select * from #tempSP as s

MERGE [dbo].[test_table] as d

USING #tempSP as s

ON (d.unique = s.unique)

WHEN MATCHED AND d.unique = s.unique

THEN UPDATE SET d.unique = s.unique, d.[CALL_TIME] = s.{CALL_TIME], d.[ACTUAL_STOP] = s.[ACTUAL_STOP], d.[CAR] = s.[CAR]

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ([unique], [CALL_TIME], [ACTUAL_STOP], [CAR])
                       VALUES(s.[unique],s.[CALL_TIME], s.[ACTUAL_STOP], s.[CAR])
```

This gives the error 'A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.'

Comment: Have you considered Partition swapping? I.e. load into a staging table and then swap partitions with your reporting table? Kendra Little posted a video how-to here: https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/

Comment: Thanks, that's not something I've heard, I'll have a look

Comment: Please can you add a full example of what you want with table before insertion, table of record to add (or select) and table after insertion ? I have some difficulties to see what you want.

Comment: How do you uniquely identify a row there? if it by 'unique' then your MERGE is right have ON 'unique' but you will also have to check if values for other columns are same or different. If different, you will have to update. Saying that, if the concern is the report's source, then I don't think MERGE will be helpful either because MERGE operation will take some time and you may have to play with locking.

Comment: From the data sample, your table appears to be unique on the combination of [unique], [call_time] and [car] (or perhaps just [unique] and [car]?), not on [unique] alone (but then your query examples don't refer to [car] at all!)  Your MERGE .. ON clause needs to include all the columns that uniquely identify the row you want to update i.e. from what I see, it should be `ON d.unique = s.unique AND d.call_time = s.call_time AND d.car = s.car` (or possibly `ON d.unique = s.unique AND d.car = s.car`). In the UPDATE SET part you need only set the column(s) that may change i.e. stop_time, call_time?

Comment: @user9601310 my mistake, missed adding CAR in the example, amended now

Comment: @user9601310 I'm currently testing your suggestion adjusting the ON. That does make sense, I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: Ok so the suggestion provided by @user9601310 did solve the GROUP BY error I was getting. It also updates the ACTUAL_STOP where there was a NULL value and inputs the new value, which is great. However, it keeps the original row which had the NULL value in. So causing a duplication which I don't want.

Comment: Suggests to me, given the original row is retained, that perhaps the MERGE is doing an INSERT not an UPDATE? Which would possibly mean your ON conditions are not quite right. It's a bit difficult to tell from what you've provided. It would help to have a small reproducible example to demonstrate the issue and to test against.